# How to get maximum performance on HP Proliant server running CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, cpu, hp

I'm trying to get constant maximum performance on my HP Proliant server running CentOS 7. Current configuration of using intel_pstate driver which varies clock speed between 1.2GHz - 2.4GHz isn't working. I want to fix the clock speed at 2.4GHz and the scaling frequency governor "performance" isn't allowing me to do that.

Comment: When you talk about "maximum performance" is to have the CPU running at its maximum frequency all the time?

Comment: @Paradox: Yes sir. That would be an ideal environment for me. Thanks!

Comment: Not using maximum frequency is a feature not a bug. It is the expected behavior. _Intel Turbo Boost Technology is a way to automatically run the processor core faster than the marked frequency. The processor must be working in the power, temperature, and specification limits of the thermal design power (TDP). This results in increased performance of both single and multithreaded applications. There is no need to install any software or application to support Intel® Turbo Boost Technology._ Unless your CPU does not increase its frequency under load, you have no problem.

Comment: @Paradox: Thanks for pointing towards Turbo Boost. I will retain stock config & enable Turbo Boost and try out.

Comment: @Kstart174 Unless you have some weird setting in the BIOS, it should be enabled by default (or not even able to choose). It is very likely that it's enabled and you did not notice that your CPU frequency was higher under load. Or that the temperature around your CPU is too high to avoid throttling.

Comment: Many servers throttle back when CPU temp rises. You may wish to consider, if your particular model of ProLiant permits, added cooling, as well as looking to see where your bottlenecks are (memory vs disk vs CPU).

Comment: @Paradox: Just tried and Turbo wasn't enabled. I can now go upto 3.4Ghz. Thanks!
K7AAY: I've pretty good cooling system and looks like that is not a bottleneck (at least for now).